# KML to SHP with elevation not equal to Z value

Tags: shapefile, kml

Can I convert a Google Earth KML file to a shapefile with the elevation coordinates not as Z values?

I can add a vector layer using a KML file and then save it as a shapefile but apparently the elevations as saved as Z values which I cannot have in the application into which I need to import the resulting shapefile.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify the software you are using after google earth (I suspect it is ArcGIS).

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the shapefile using either an **[Open Source](http://www.faunalia.com/content/transfer-3d-shapefiles-z-values-table-attributes)** or **[ArcGIS for Desktop](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30455)** procedure.